# Camera can't be changed to another

Tags: camera

I have an issue with the cameras. It usually worked fine just to now. I added a camera to have another point of view. I must had touch something unwanted because I can't change to any other camera.

I can switch camera in Scene menu, but it does not seem to do anything, the first camera keeps the focus.

I did try to create a new project and play around with cameras and all went fine.

Can you guys have encountered that issue too? how do I fix it?

Comment: An active camera is not the same as an active object. Try selecting the camera to switch to, then use the Spacebar search function and type "Set active object as camera".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the 3pointedit post.

I had to set the Local Camera option to the proper object(camera in my case).
I used to just change the Scene's camera but apparently do not work anymore. At least I know another way to change it.

[image]

[Update]

Here is the button I hitted by mistake :

[image]

Now I can change the active camera directly from the scene menu.

- Button active : only camera can be selected as camera from the Scene menu.
- Button inactive : Camera in Scene menu do nothing, but in the first picture, you can set any object as a camera.